# Unknown property for PHP class

Tags: php

I have a class `CategoryModel` defined in part as

```
class CategoryModel {

    private $id, $categoryText;

    public function createWithParams($id, $categoryText) {
        $instance = new self();
        $instance->id = $id;
        $instance->categoryText = array();

        if ($categoryText != null)
            $this->categoryText[] = $categoryText;

        return $instance;

    }

    .... further model code 

}
```

When I call this function in a phpunit test, I get the printout

```
    Exception: Unknown property 'categoryText' for class 'QuestionDaoTest'
```

that centers on the line

```
$this->categoryText[] = $categoryText();
```

I changed the array value assignation code to

```
if ($categoryText != null)
  $this->categoryText = array($categoryText);
else
  $this->categoryText = array();
```

But this now gives me an null error when I execute a `in_array` key check on the array in the setter method

```
public function addCategoryText($categoryText) {
  if (!in_array($categoryText, $this->categoryText)) {
    $this->categoryText[] = $categoryText;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
```

What is the reasoning behind these errors and how can I resolve them?

EDIT
Problem solved.

```
$this->categoryText[] = $categoryText;
```

does not equate to

```
$instance->categoryText[] = $categoryText;
```

I was not referring to the instanciated class object, thus the null access issues.

Comment: Perhaps because the property is private?

Comment: `$categoryText` is `private`.

Comment: but that shouldn't stop me from accessing and declaring the variable.  I implement this similar constructor philosophy in many other model classes and this is the first time I've come across it.  Albeit, this is the first time I'm instanciating an array within the constructor method

Comment: Well the error clearly states that you're trying to access the property from another class. You cannot do that with private members (unless you use reflection). If need to access them from a child class, you shouldn't be using private properties anyway

Comment: It is a unit test that I'm running this on, and the only time I've come across this issue while following the same variable declaration pattern.  The variable has getters and setters.  This function is a constructor variant that allows me to use multiple constructors when necessary rather than relying on the default `__construct()` function.  See my edit for more information.

Comment: @Jason: Are you extending `UserModel`? Is `createWithAllParams` called from the extended class at any point?

Comment: @OneTrickPony, No, the model class is isolated from an inheritance perspective.  Each model is essentially a plain old php data object that models a single row in the database table.

Comment: `CategoryModel` = `QuestionDaoTest`? What happens if you replace `new self()` with `new static()` ?

Comment: It works, but all other setter methods are broken for class instances.

Comment: Your comments are misleading. if `static` !== `self` then you did extend the class :) Please post your real code

Comment: I found out what the issue was.  `$instance->categoryText = array()` != `$this->categoryText = array()`. Chalk it up to a brain fart and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

`private` members are only visible to methods within the same class. They are not visible outside the class, and not visible to descendant objects.

The error clearly states it's occuring within an instance of `QuestionDaoTest`, so any private members declared within the parent `CategoryModel` will **NOT** be visible.

You want `protected`, which hides the member from the outside world, but is visible within the object and also visible in descendant objects.

Comment: This is a method in this class which gets the error, though: this is not right!

Comment: yes, it is. `private $categoryText` is declared in the `CategoryModel` object. OP is trying to access it from within an instance of `QuestionDaoTest`.

Comment: No, the error is 8 lines below the variable declaration IN THIS CLASS. Doesn't matter what other class is extending this. Otherwise no getter/setter on private variable would ever work for inheritance???

Comment: @AxelAmthor is correct.  This is a private variable for the class, with its own getter and setter.  What I am trying to do is initialize it via a constructor method.  As PHP does not allow multiple constructors a la Java, I write my own constructor methods to allow for other initializations beyond the default `__construct()` method.

Comment: **read the error message**. The getters/setters in CategoryModel can access their own private attributes all they want. But the error message **CLEARLY** states that the access attempt is being done from an instance of `QuestionDaoTest`.

Comment: @Marc B if the object instantiates QuestionDaoTest which extends CategoryModel, errors will show on the very outer class. Unless you don't know filename and line-no you can't determine WHERe the error is.

Comment: @Jason then you should try to initialize `$categoryText` as empty array in one of these constructors like in my answer.

Comment: @MarcB, the only difference between this constructor and the 8 others I've written for models in this project is that it initializes and assigns a variable to an array.  All other variable assignations work and currently 30 unit tests and over 150 assertions all pass.  That is up until this particular model class.

Comment: @AxelAmthor, I tried that, but got the same error regardless.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class CategoryModel {

   private $id = null;
   private $categoryText = null;

   ....

   function __construct()
   {
        $this->categoryText = array();
        // more initialization ....
```

It's a bad feature of php to not to **FORCE** to initialize variables like in Java i.e., which always result in these errors:  your variable isn't an array and therefor the $var[] operator won't work. You need to create an array first.